# Error in adding firebase messaging to flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to add firebase messaging to my flutter app and I want to register the plugin in `application.java`

but my app gets stuck at
 `Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...`
and when I try to launch it gives me an error that it keeps stopping.

the file contains errors in importing the package

My Code:

```java
package com.example.flutter_fcm_java_test;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
//Error in this import
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //can't read firebase messaging service
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
    }
}
```

I've added the firebase messaging plugin dependency in my pubspec.yaml file and changed my name tag in the manifest to .Application and it can read it.

please help me.

My directory to Application.java

C:\Users...\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_fcm_java_test\android\app\src\main\java\com\example\flutter_fcm_java_test

the file extension is java source file

Comment: same error for me !

Answer (score 4):

Any error message with the building? If faced message as

```
[firebase_messaging] class file for com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService not found
```

Try following resolution (tested with firebase_messaging: ^6.0.3) by adding firebase messaging dependency in your app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  // ...

  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
}
```